# Using index and match to do a lookup both vertically and horizontally

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, vba

I have one column of data on a sheet and each cell contains a value that could be found in an array on another sheet. I'm trying to find a function where if it finds the value in the array in sheet 2 from the column in sheet 1, then it returns the value in the leftmost column.

Here's an example of the data:

*sheet 1*

```
| AH2377507 |
| 2188622   |
| EA404278  |
| AH885430  |
```

*sheet 2*

```
aaa | 1874379 | AH2377507 | EA2377507 | PS2377507 | 67004276 | 949529 | AH2065634
bbb | 1938614 | 2186486   | 2188622   | 2188708
ccc | 919973  | AH404278  | EA404278  | PS404278 | 2188746
ddd | 960929  | AH885430  | EA885430  | PS885430
```

So when '2188622' is found in sheet 2, it returns 'bbb'.

Also the number of columns with data in sheet 2 varies from row to row, so there are blank cells in the array, if that matters.

I've tried nesting vlookp in hlookup and vise-versa as well as nesting hlookup in a index/match, but neither of those ideas worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a bit more than just a `INDEX/MATCH`

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$B$1:$F$4=Sheet1!$A1)*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4)))
```

Assuming your *Sheet1* data is in `A1:A4` and your *Sheet2* data is in `A1:F4`.

**Note** the `ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4)` at the end has nothing to do with your data. The range must always start at `A1` and if you have `10` records in *Sheet2* then it must end at `A10`, for example.

---

*More info*...

Because your lookup value comes from an 2d array, rather than a single row/colum, you can't use `MATCH`. We need to simulate a match though so that is where the `SUMPRODUCT` comes in. If you had the following array in `A1:B2`

```
a   a
a   b
```

We can perform the logical operation `A1:B2="b"`. This creates an array like this

```
FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   TRUE
```

Remembering that `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0` if we multiply by `ROW(A1:A2)` then that array becomes

```
0*1 0*1    =    0    0
0*2 1*2    =    0    2
```

So you can see the `SUM` of this array is `2` which is exactly the position we are looking for (it's what the `MATCH` would have returned)

So we wrap it all in a `SUMPRODUCT` like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:B2="b")*ROW(A1:A2))
```

And you've got your answer

Comment: Could your `ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4)` be `ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4)`? - that would make it more obvious that the `$A$4` should be linked to the number of items in `Sheet2`.  And should `...=Sheet1!$A$1` be `...=Sheet1!$A1` so that the formula can be copied to other rows?

Comment: I had to think about that but yeah, I agree. Thank you!

Comment: Someone interrupted me with a work question after I read your original comment but before I had a chance to respond - now I'm glad that they did - it meant I didn't need to think up an explanation :D

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you meant by not moving $A$1 if data doesn't start in row 1.  (You need an array of numbers starting from 1, not the actual rows corresponding to the data.)  You could potentially get around that by using `(ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4)+1-ROW(Sheet2!$A$1))`, where `$A$1:$A$4` is the actual range of data, and `$A$1` is the first cell in the actual range of data.  But I don't know whether it would be easier to explain that, or to explain that the `:$A$4` has to be set to the number of rows in the lookup data range even if that lookup range is in `$A$47:$F$50`.

Comment: Do you think it's worth making a formula more complicated just so it's easier to explain how to implement it, or should we always be looking to explain it better? I edited to hopefully make it a bit easier to understand, and along with your suggestion, I also considered changing the last bit to `ROW(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,,,10,1))`, explaining that `10` is the number of rows in the table in *Sheet2*... I'm just reluctant to add complexity.